# Meteor app crashes when trying to populate collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

This code works:

```
Schemas.City = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: 'City',
        unique: true
    }
});

Cities = new Mongo.Collection('cities');
Cities.attachSchema(Schemas.City);
```

This code works:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
}
```

This code works:

```
Cities.insert([{
    name: 'Warszawa'
}, {
    name: 'Krakow'
}]);
```

But this code doesn't:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Cities.find().count() == 0) {
        Cities.insert([{
            name: 'Warszawa'
        }, {
            name: 'Krakow'
        }]);
    }
}
```

I'm having the following error in console on server:

```
W20150911-13:34:52.281(4)? (STDERR) Error: 0 is not allowed by the schema
W20150911-13:34:52.281(4)? (STDERR)     at getErrorObject (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:417:1)
```

As you can see, I use [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) package to control data manipulations so that they stick to schema. The schema is simple and it only requires that there are no duplicates.

What's the right direction to move to discover the problem? Am I missing something?

### Update: no arrays when inserting in Meteor

Okay, I got it. In Meteor, it's not possible to insert multiple entries into a collection using

```
Collection.insert([entry1, entry2, ...])
```

syntax. This, in turn, works:

```
Collection.insert(entry1);
Collection.insert(entry2);
```

So the problem is solved, mostly partially.

Comment: I think this is the modifier you are looking for: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`batchInsert` should be used in Meteor instead of `insert` in this case:

```
Collection.batchInsert([entry1, entry2, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
var bulk = Meteor.Collection.get('cities').rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
cities.forEach(function(city){
  bulk.insert(city)
})
bulk.execute();
```

The above code is untested, but should work.  If you want look into `initializeUnorderedBulkOp`